# GitHub API: create a repository from template authenticated as installation

Tags: git, api, github, github-api

I'm attempting to create a repository from a repository template via GitHub's API for an organization. `https://api.github.com/repos/{template_org_name}/{template_repo}/generate`. I'm trying to do so with a GitHub app authenticated as an installation with administrative permissions on the organization. I'm unable to successfully create a repository and get a `Resource not accessible by integration` response. I am, however, able to create a repository via this same endpoint using my own GitHub user's personal access token. I'm inclined to think that this endpoint is only available as a user-to-server request, but have not had any luck looking at docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-repository-using-a-repository-template). I understand that it is technically a beta endpoint, so maybe that is my answer.

I checked that I am using the right "Accept" header as well in the request (`Accept: application/vnd.github.baptiste-preview+json`). Anyone have any luck with this endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers here have become outdated in a good way. At some point between when everyone answered this post to my answer now, GitHub updated the API to allow for this.

There is an API endpoint that provides this functionality:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template

Template repos have a `/generate` endpoint in the API now which allows you send a JSON body with the details of the new repo you want to create.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/TEMPLATE_OWNER/TEMPLATE_REPO/generate \
  -d '{"owner":"NEW-REPO-OWNER","name":"NEW-REPO-NAME","description":"Repo created from a template","include_all_branches":false,"private":false}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the endpoint to create a repository from a template is only available as a `user-to-server` request and is not enabled for GitHub apps. It is very subtle, but only API actions that have an information icon next to the name in the documentation are available to GitHub apps.
[Example of information icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weLxu.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `user-to-server` requests are?

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 `user-to-server` requests are when a GitHub app acts on behalf of a user. The request must be authenticated with a user's access token. More info here https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps/#identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps

Comment: I recently got an update from GitHub that GitHub apps authenticated as an installation are able to create a repository from a repository template _within the same organization_. Meaning the template repository and repository being created must belong to the same organization.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this also. It turns out it is only available as a `user-to-server` request but can be done with Github Apps as documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps

At a high level:

1. Select "Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation" in your apps settings and add a callback URL in your app
2. Get the code from the redirect (on installation) which looks something like this: https://xxx.ngrok.io/?code=xxx&installation_id=xxx&setup_action=install
3. Exchange the code for a regular access token at `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` or `exchange_code_for_token` in octokit.rb. This needs: `client_id`, `client_secret` and the `code` from the redirect.
4. Use the returned access code to access the API directly as a user. i.e. `github = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: "xxx")`
5. Create a repo for the user `github.create_repository('xxx', private: true)`

A additional point of confusion for me was the difference between `app_id` and `client_id`. Both are listed on your app page but you need the `client_id`!